# Ruby tk: draw while program is in execution

Tags: ruby, tk-toolkit

To display whatever elements that have been created with Tk `Tk.mainloop` has to be called at the end of the program. But what if I want to draw/display different sections of the GUI as the application goes on?

More particularly my situation is the tic-tac-toe game. First I draw the board:

```
def initialize_board
  @root = TkRoot.new { minsize(400, 450) }
  @root.title = "Tic-tac-toe"

  @cv = TkCanvas.new @root
  @cv.place('height' => 350, 'width' => 350, 'x' => 50, 'y' => 100)
  TkcLine.new @cv, 0, 100, 300, 100, width: 5
  TkcLine.new @cv, 0, 200, 300, 200, width: 5
  TkcLine.new @cv, 100, 0, 100, 300, width: 5
  TkcLine.new @cv, 200, 0, 200, 300, width: 5

  @menu = TkMenu.new
  one = TkMenu.new @menu
  @menu.add('cascade', :menu => one, :label => 'Select player')
  one.add('command', :label => 'Human first', :command => proc { set_players_and_play(HumanPlayer, ComputerPlayer) })
  one.add('command', :label => 'Computer first', :command => proc { set_players_and_play(ComputerPlayer, HumanPlayer) })

  @root.menu @menu

  Tk.mainloop
end
```

And then in the console the user is asked for the position he wants to choose, and when he does the marker is supposed to be displayed in the board, and so on:

```
def print_board
  (1..9).each do |i|
    position, marker = i, @board[i]
    if marker.eql? "X"
      case position
      when 1
        TkcLine.new @cv, 20, 20, 80, 80, width: 2
        TkcLine.new @cv, 20, 80, 80, 20, width: 2
        #Tk.mainloop
      end
    elsif marker == "O"
    end
  end
end
```

However all the markers are not displayed on the board until the games ends. How can I draw these markers as the game goes on?

Answer (score 1):

> [W]hat if I want to draw/display different sections of the GUI as the application goes on?
>
> [A]ll the markers are not displayed on the board until the games ends. How can I draw these markers as the game goes on?

The answer is in your code, already!

Even after calling `Tk.mainloop`, any desired Ruby code can still run, if it's in a callback.

Your code fragment, `:command => proc { set_players_and_play(HumanPlayer, ComputerPlayer) }` contains a `proc` literal. That `proc` is an example of a Tk callback. Your code fragment instructs the Tk GUI system to invoke that `proc` when the menu item is selected.

So, as you can see, menu items have callbacks. Many other Tk widgets do, as well.

I added some lines to your code to avoid runtime errors (and noted where I did so). Now it draws an "X" in the first position (when "Computer first" is selected from the menu):

```rb
require 'tk' # Added this line.

def initialize_board
  @root = TkRoot.new { minsize(400, 450) }
  @root.title = "Tic-tac-toe"

  @cv = TkCanvas.new @root
  @cv.place('height' => 350, 'width' => 350, 'x' => 50, 'y' => 100)
  TkcLine.new @cv, 0, 100, 300, 100, width: 5
  TkcLine.new @cv, 0, 200, 300, 200, width: 5
  TkcLine.new @cv, 100, 0, 100, 300, width: 5
  TkcLine.new @cv, 200, 0, 200, 300, width: 5

  @menu = TkMenu.new
  one = TkMenu.new @menu
  @menu.add('cascade', :menu => one, :label => 'Select player')
  one.add('command', :label => 'Human first', :command => proc { set_players_and_play(HumanPlayer, ComputerPlayer) })
  one.add('command', :label => 'Computer first', :command => proc { set_players_and_play(ComputerPlayer, HumanPlayer) })

  @root.menu @menu

  Tk.mainloop
end

def print_board
  (1..9).each do |i|
    position, marker = i, @board[i]
    if marker.eql? "X"
      case position
      when 1
        TkcLine.new @cv, 20, 20, 80, 80, width: 2
        TkcLine.new @cv, 20, 80, 80, 20, width: 2
        #Tk.mainloop
      end
    elsif marker == "O"
    end
  end
end

# Added these lines, below:

HumanPlayer = 'Human player'
ComputerPlayer = 'Computer player'

size = 3 * 3
@board = Array.new size + 1, ''

def set_players_and_play(player_first, player_second)
  puts "#{player_first} first, then #{player_second}"
  if ComputerPlayer == player_first
    @board[1] = 'X'
    print_board
  end
end

initialize_board
print_board
```

This worked for me using Ruby 2.2.5 (with Tk 8.5.12) on Windows 7.